# VS Code not providing Auto completion for linked scripts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, vscode-extensions

When I insert a linked script tag in the head section of an HTML page, VS Code does not provide me autocompletion for objects and methods available in the linked javascript. [Screengrab of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjo0b.png).
It works out of the box in Webstorm and Visual Studio.

I tried downloading the script to the local folder and link it from there but autocompletion would still not work.

Comment: To add some more specific details I have linked the Vue.js file found at https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js. I believe this should automatically give me intellisense for the methods on the Vue class e.g. Vue.createApp. But this does not seem to work. Must be something obvious I am missing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you find IntelliSense has stopped working, the language service may not be running. Try restarting VS Code and this should solve the issue. If you are still missing IntelliSense features after installing a language extension, open an issue in the repository of the language extension.

Also, if you don't get autocompletion when using a tag or script, you can bring it up by holding down the ctrl + space.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, autocomplete is working perfectly for all other cases. The autocomplete kicks in even when I write JavaScript in the script block. Only when I use a linked Javascript, the autocomplete fails to work. I also have Volar installed.